# constrOptim initial values

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, linear-programming

I'm attempting to use the `constrOptim()` function in R to optimise:

`2x + 2y + 3z`

subject to:

`-2x + y + z <= 1`

`4x - y + 3z <= 3`

`x, y, z >= 0`

What I have so far is this:

```
ui = matrix(c(2,-1,-1,-4, 1,-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                     nrow = 5,
                     byrow = T)

ci = c(-1, -3, 0, 0, 0)
theta = c(0, 1, 0)

constrOptim(
  theta = theta,
  f = func,
  ui = ui,
  ci = ci)
```

This gives me the error that "*initial value is not in the interior of the feasible region*". However, if I run the following as a test:

```
ui = matrix(c(2,-1,-1,-4, 1,-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
                     nrow = 5,
                     byrow = T)

ci = c(-1, -3, 0, 0, 0)
theta = c(0, 1, 0)

ui %*% theta - ci
```

I get `(0  4  0  1  0)`, which is definitely >=0.

My question is why do I get an error telling me that `ui %*% theta - ci` is not >= 0, when it clearly is? What am I missing?

Edit: managed to sort it out thanks to [Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%c3%a9phane-laurent).

Any ideas how best to plot the feasible region in R? Any useful packages?

Comment: This is a linear problem. Such problems are better solved with LP solvers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting value must be in the *interior* of the feasible region, so you need `> 0` and not `>= 0`. You can use theta = `c(0.1, 1, 0.1)`

```
ui = matrix(c(2,-1,-1,-4, 1,-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
            nrow = 5,
            byrow = T)
ci = c(-1, -3, 0, 0, 0)
theta = c(0.1, 1, 0.1)

all(ui %*% theta - ci > 0) # TRUE

constrOptim(
  theta = theta,
  f = function(xyz) c(crossprod(c(2,2,3), xyz)),
  grad = NULL,
  ui = ui,
  ci = ci)
```

BTW, it seems obvious to me that the solution is `c(0,0,0)`.

Comment: Great, thanks! Not sure why the documentation has a `>=o` then...  

I forgot to mention that I needed to _maximise_ the function, so the solution isn't `c(0, 0, 0)` but `c(2, 5, 4.043353)`.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of error has been explained from [the answer by Stéphane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60280692/12158757).

An alternative of `constrOptim` is to use `fmincon` from package `pracma`, and you can run the code without any error even with initial values on the boundary, i.e., `theta = c(0,1,0)`

```
ui = matrix(c(2,-1,-1,-4, 1,-3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1),
            nrow = 5,
            byrow = T)
ci = c(-1, -3, 0, 0, 0)
theta = c(0, 1, 0)
func <- function(v) crossprod(c(2,2,3),v)

res <- pracma::fmincon(theta,
                       f = func,
                       A = -ui,
                       b = -ci)
```

such that

```
> res
$par
[1] 0 0 0

$value
     [,1]
[1,]    0

$convergence
[1] 0

$info
$info$lambda
$info$lambda$lower
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0

$info$lambda$upper
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    0
[3,]    0

$info$lambda$ineqlin
[1] 0 0 2 2 3


$info$grad
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    2
[3,]    3

$info$hessian
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1 0.00    0
[2,]    0 0.03    0
[3,]    0 0.00    1
```